# Does an object moving at constant speed lose energy in space?

Tags: forces, energy, space

Energy expenditure would be equal to force times distance. Since there is no force applied to an object moving at constant speed in space there should be no energy expenditure.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's first law says an object at rest or moving in a straight line at constant speed will remain at rest or continue to move at constant speed unless acted upon by a net external force.

If outer space was a perfect vacuum free of any particles, the object would move at constant speed and not lose any kinetic energy. But outer space is not a perfect vacuum. To quote Wikipedia: "Outer space is not completely empty- it is a hard vacuum containing  a low density of particles, predominantly a plasma of hydrogen and helium, as well as electromagnetic radiation, magnetic fields, neutrinos, dust and cosmic rays".

So eventually, due to collisions with particles, the object will transfer its kinetic energy to those particles and slow down.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is completely isolated, then there is no energy expenditure. But the object attains a particular velocity due to application of force, when this velocity is attained then force application can be removed(so before that instant energy supplied by the agent applying force helps in providing kinetic energy) but after attainment of that velocity $v$, there is no energy expenditure.
But if there are several forces acting on the object such that their vector sum is 0, then the energy expenditure takes place. Energy given by all the sources responsible for applying force in the direction of displacement is taken by sources responsible for applying force in the direction opposite to the displacement of object, provided the object is initially in the velocity $v$ before the application of forces.

Comment: "But if there are several forces acting on the object such that their vector sum is 0, then the energy expenditure takes place. " If the vector sum of the forces acting on the object is zero, then the net force on the object is zero and there is no change in its velocity and no energy expenditure nor gain.

Comment: Overall no energy expenditure takes place, but individually the sources which applies the force exchanges energy with each other. Suppose object initially has velocity v (constant), thus having kinetic energy $(mv^2/2)$. Now several forces start acting on the object $F=\sum_i F_i=\sum_jF_j-\sum_kF_k=0$, where j indices are used for the forces in the direction of displacement and k for the opposite to the displacement.If there is a displacement xof tue body, then $F.dx=0\implies\sum_jF_j.dx-\sum_kF_k.dx=0$,

Comment: So, the "sources" which apply force in the direction of displacement looses energy and that equal energy is taken by the sources which apply the force in the direction opposite to displacement.So overal energy excuange of the sources which apply forces + energy possesed by the object = $(\sum_jF_j.dx-\sum_kF_k.dx)+\frac{mv^2}{2}=0+\frac{mv^2}{2}=\frac{mv^2}{2}$